# variance of sample mean using srswor

Tags: sample, survey-sampling

1. while deriving variance of sample mean in case of **SRSWOR**, i came through this.
   [image]

how did the highlighted term came there. while solving it, there should be 2Cov(yi,yj) but that term is not there.

2. in texts , it is mentioned that

[image]

How did the the highlighted term came there?

Comment: This is a matter of reading mathematical notation--there's no statistical content.  Write out the sums explicitly in the case $n=2.$ That will clearly show you what the notation means.

Comment: The expectation of a sum is equal to the sum of the expectations